# How to update sub array with unique id in mongodb

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I have a collection with the following details. Here is the mock data with the necessary info:

```
    [{
    dealId: "deal1",
    details: {
        name: "name"
    },
    product: [{
        pId: "pId1",
        item: [{
            itemId: "itemId1",
            details: {
                type: {
                    name: "type1"
                },
            }
        },{
            itemId: "itemId2",
            details: {
                type: {
                    name: "type2"
                },
            }
        }, ...]
    },{
        pId: "pId2",
        item: [{
            itemId: "itemId2",
            details: {
                type: {
                    name: "type1"
                }
            }
        }, ...]
    }, ...]
}, ...]
```

Every product can have many items. I need to update the products with adding unique aid for every item

I want this kind of response after query

```
    [{
    dealId: "deal1",
    details: {
        name: "name"
    },
    product: [{
        pId: "pId1",
        item: [{
            itemId: "itemId1",
            details: {
                type: {
                    aid: "random uuid1",
                    name: "type1"
                },
            }
        },{
            itemId: "itemId2",
            details: {
                type: {
                    aid: "random uuid2",
                    name: "type2"
                },
            }
        }, ...]
    },{
        pId: "pId2",
        item: [{
            itemId: "itemId2",
            details: {
                type: {
                    aid: "random uuid3",
                    name: "type3"
                }
            }
        }, ...]
    }, ...]
}, ...]
```

I have tried with different queries but it didn't work..

Answer (score 1):

Use [`$function`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/function/). New in version **4.4**.

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "artifacts": {
        "$function": {
          "body": "function (ar) {return ar.map(x => { x.item.map(i => {i.details.type[\"aid\"]=new ObjectId(); return i;});  return x;})}",
          "args": [
            "$product"
          ],
          "lang": "js"
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  "multi": true
})
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/I0HaE1ivzqD)